# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Staffing Management Plan

Tags: from-english, терміни

"Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту ""PMBOK та PM ISO українською"". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Варіанти:

- План управління персоналом
- План управління штатним розкладом
- План управління набором штату

Визначення терміну Staffing Management Plan [там](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Staffing_Management_Plan) таке:

> **Staffing Management Plan.** A component of the resource management plan that describes when and how team members will be acquired and how long they will be needed. See also resource management plan.

Answer (score 1):

- *План комплектування штатом/персоналом.*

Комплектування має ту перевагу, що його можна розглядати як те, що включає і наймання, і звільнення.

Також можна *план вербування персоналу*. Так буде менше омонімів.

Також можна зробити, щоб було слово в слово як в оригіналі:

- *План керування вербуванням.*

Answer (score -1):

Staffing Management Plan

План комплектації менеджменту

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainial Language SE! Будь ласка, поясніть чому саме так ви пропонуєте перекласти цей вираз (метою цього сайту є не тільки дати відповідь, але й пояснити чому саме вона найкраще відповідає потребам того, хто поставив питання). Також зверніть увагу, що у питанні є визначення цього терміну, яке суперечить перекладу, який ви запропонували.